# Mouse over not working

Tags: javascript

I have a div which is waiting for a move over event. This then places a div with information for it.

The problem i have is getting to remove the event listener properly & also remove the div it created... for some reason it cannot find the child div that i made.

So this is my script that i tried:

```
div.addEventListener('mouseover',bubble_info,false);


function bubble_info(e){
    var x = e.pageX + 50; //push it 50px to the right
    var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        div.style.top = e.pageY;
        div.style.left = x;
        div.className = 'bubble';
        div.innerHTML = 'Testing this div';     
        this.appendChild(div);

//stop firing if mouse moves around on the parent as it is still "over" the parent
    this.removeEventListener('mouseover',bubble_info,false); 

//when mouse out occurs the below should fire
    this.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){clear_hover.call(this,div);},false);
}


function clear_hover(child){
    //remove the bubble div we made
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child); 

    //remove the mouse out as we are now out
    this.removeEventListener('mouseout',function(){clear_hover.call(this,div);},false);

    //re-add the mouseover listener encase user hovers over it again
    this.addEventListener('mouseover',bubble_info,false);
}
```

Can any one see the mistakes i am making here, just can't work out why it all goes wrong for mouse out.

Dev tools shows `Cannot call method 'removeChild' of null`

Comment: can't you just call the clear_hover like this `clear_hover(div)`?

Comment: Well i could. But I have always thought looking up the child's parentNode instead of just passing `this` would be more taxing for the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is suggesting that `child.parentNode == null`. So, the element doesn't have a `parentNode` to be removed from.

```
if (child.parentNode)
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
```

But, that only fixes the symptom. The actual issue is that the event handler isn't being removed, so it keeps running with subsequent `mouseout` occurrences.

Though the following functions are similar, they need to be the same for the removal to succeed.

```
this.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){clear_hover.call(this,div);},false);
```

```
this.removeEventListener('mouseout',function(){clear_hover.call(this,div);},false);
```

So, you'll need to save a reference to the `function` to remove it:

```
function bubble_info(e){
    var ...;

    function on_mouseout() {
        // pass a reference to the `function` itself
        clear_hover.call(this, div, on_mouseout);
    }

    // ...

    this.addEventListener('mouseout',on_mouseout,false);
}

function clear_hover(child, handler){
    //remove the bubble div we made
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child); 

    //remove the mouse out as we are now out
    this.removeEventListener('mouseout',handler,false);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Surely a parentNode is bound to exist i did append to a div after all ?

Comment: @Dave It is the 1st time. But, because the event handler isn't actually being removed, it tries to remove the element again, and again, and etc.